# Remove ajax from the form submission in PHPLucidFrame

Tags: php, ajax, forms, phplucidframe

I'm using [PHPLucidFrame](http://www.phplucidframe.com) the version 1.1.1. I found that LucidFrame makes by default every form submission using ajax. Is there any way to create forms without using ajax? I just want to submit my forms with traditional HTTP request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [its documentation](http://phplucidframe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html#creating-ajax-form), you can simply add `class="no-ajax"` to the `<form>` tag.

```
<form name="yourFormName" id="yourFormId" method="post" class="no-ajax">
    <div class="message error"></div>
    <!-- 
        HTML input elements here as usual 
    -->
    <?php Form::token(); ?>
</form>
<?php Form::respond('yourFormId', Validation::$errors); ?>
```

If your form action handling is in the same page, the `Form::respond()` call will automatically display the error message into `<div class="message error"></div>` and highlight the error fields.